# Wordpress search results page listing non-relevant contents

Tags: wordpress, search

there's an issue on one of my wordpress based webpage. When I enter keyword into search input field on the search results page lot of non-relevant contents are listing. I changed theme but I got the same issue.

Comment: Hey Norbert, what is your question? Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask **How to ask a question on stackoverflow**. That being said, what is non-relevant content for you? Do you get pages and posts? Describe a typical query that would return non-relevant results... etc. Give us some context, is it a custom website (built from scratch) or are you using a template, if so which one. Did you try anything to fix it, is so what did you do. Try to discribe as much as you can. Remember that non of us are next to you. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default search query is basic. If you search for a string it will output any and all related posts, pages or related content that have that string in there title, content, metas, tags, categories, taxonomies... etc. pretty much everything related or connected to it.

But thankfully you can restrict the search query, there is different ways, for example, adding the following in your `function.php` will force the search query to only output posts.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
  };
} );
```

You can also force the search query to also only search titles (which is an other way to restrict outputs. You can take a look a [this post on stackoverflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles/11826#11826).

You can basically chose to add or ignore anything, you just have to set it up. Don't forget that Wordpress is a CMS (Content Management System), not a plug and play website, that's why devs exist!

The documentation already exist and is out there, don't be shy to search for it.